# VBA Excel run macro from mother workbook on newly created workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to run the macro on the newly created workbook.
The macro has been created in my mother's workbook and I want to make it valid in the other workbook, which was created.

The following code:

```
   Dim wkb As Workbook, mwkb As Workbook

   Set mwkb = ThisWorkbook

   Set wkb = Workbooks.Add

   With wkb
   .Sheets("Sheet1").Name = "Frontsheet"
   Set fwsk = .Sheets("Frontsheet")
   With fwsk
   Dim orshape As Shape
   Set orshape = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRectangle, 80, 280, 500, 75)
   With orshape
   .Fill.Visible = msoFalse
   .Name = "ORBox"
   .OnAction = "'" & mwkb & "'!OpenPoor"
   End With
   End With
```

returns an error, that says:

**Object doesn't support this property or method**

at the line:

```
  .OnAction = "'" & mwkb & "'!OpenPoor"
```

The macro doesn't work even if I provide the fixed name of my mother's workbook instead of this variable. Then it throws an error, that the macro hasn't been found in the direction (which is different than my workbook).

The hint I found is here:
https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/assign-a-macro-to-a-shape-using-vba.373185/

I am asking about the possibility of using macro this way or maybe should it be hard coded directly in the newly created workbook?

Comment: I get *Variable not defined* on `Set fwsk = .Sheets("Frontsheet")`. Then I get *Expected End With* on `End Sub`. Finally, I get your error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Add a Shape With a Macro to a New Workbook

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub AddShapeMacro()
    
    Dim mwkb As Workbook: Set mwkb = ThisWorkbook
    Dim wkb As Workbook: Set wkb = Workbooks.Add
    'Set wkb = Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet) ' single-sheet workbook
    
    With wkb.Sheets(1)
        .Name = "Frontsheet"
        With .Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRectangle, 80, 280, 500, 75)
            .Fill.Visible = msoFalse
            .Name = "ORBox"
            .OnAction = "'" & mwkb.Name & "'!OpenPoor"
        End With
    End With

End Sub
```